# What should *(vec.begin() - 1) return?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following code:

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.push_back(10);
test.push_back(20);
test.push_back(30);
printf("%d\n", *(test.begin() - 1));
```

What is the iterator before test.begin() guaranteed to return? Will it always be 0? Or is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: I'd say that's UB.

Comment: It is definitely undefined behavior. What would you expect it to return?

Comment: ... And why are you using `printf` in C++ code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour will be undefined. **There is nothing to prevent you if you read memory that you don't own**. So you can read it but, you have no control of the area i.e. who is writing to the area? So the behaviour will be undefined.

But if you try to write at `*(test.begin()-1)` , you'd encounter error if your os is protecting the area.

Answer (score 1):

`test.begin() - 1` causes undefined behaviour  (even without dereferencing).

According to the defintion of `-` operator for Random Access Iterators in C++ standard section [random.access.iterators]/1,  this is equivalent to `--test.begin()`.

The behaviour of prefix-`--` is described by [bidirectional.iterators]/1, and it has:

> `--r` **Assertion/note pre/post-condition:** pre: there exists `s` such that `r == ++s`

However there is no `s` such that `++s == test.begin()`, so this pre-condition does not hold; therefore the behaviour is undefined.